# Using symbols and numbers for alternate spelling of words

Tags: regex, search, symbols

I'm trying to prevent words like 'password' and 'credit card' from being submitted in my form. So before I submit the it I'm just going to do a simple regex search for my banned words and any alternate spellings of those words: `p[a4@][s5][s5]w[o0]rd(\d*|\W*)`, `cr[e3]dit(.*)c[a4@]rd(\d*|\W*)`. I have a few more words I'd like to catch so I want to make sure i've got all the possible alternative for each letter of the alphabet.

```
a - [a4@]
b - [b8]
c - [c]
d - [d]
e - [e3]
f - [f]
g - [g]
h - [h]
i - [i1]
j - [j]
k - [k]
l - [l1]
m - [m]
n - [n]
o - [o0]
p - [p]
q - [q]
r - [r]
s - [s5]
t - [t]
u - [u]
v - [v]
w - [w]
x - [x]
y - [y]
z - [z]
```

Comment: Are you asking whether people can think of other leetspeak versions of the input letters?

Comment: unclear inexact question

Comment: @Vorsprung How can I make it more exact for you?

Comment: show actual code you want to run.  Show actual desired input and output.  Show the errors or undesired output you are getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any undesired errors I just want to make sure I'm catching everything.

Comment: I wonder what the notion "catching everything" means?  Still in the dark

Comment: he's asking if any other characters look similar to letters :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few off the top of my head

- s - $
- t - 7, +
- g - 6 (G), 9 (g)
- i - !
- c - (

Comment: though I don't think you'll be able to catch things like \/\/ for w...